# Vim pymode throws "invalid syntax" error on async function definition

Tags: python, vim, python-mode

I'm currently developing some async python in vim and have [pymode](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode) installed as a plugin. But I'm having an issue with file linting because the linter gets hung up on the first (and valid) `async` definition and won't lint the rest of the file.

```py
@user_bp.get('/api/v1/user')
async def get_users(request): # `invalid syntax` error on 'async', linting stops here
    with scoped_session() as session:
        statement = User.__table__.select()
        users = [dict(user) for user in session.execute(statement)]

    return json(users)

# ... many lines of unlinted code
```

My vimrc has the language set to `python3` and syntax checker to `pep8`, but this still cant seem to shake the error.

```
" ~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim

setlocal shiftwidth=4
setlocal tabstop=4
setlocal softtabstop=4
setlocal smarttab

" PYMODE : enable
let g:pymode = 1
let g:pymode_python = 'python3'


" PYMODE : disable the following
let g:pymode_virtualenv = 0
let g:pymode_folding = 0
let g:pymode_indent  = 0
let g:pymode_doc     = 0
let g:pymode_rope    = 0

" PYMODE.Linting
let g:pymode_lint            = 1
let g:pymode_lint_write      = 1
let g:pymode_lint_unmodified = 0
let g:pymode_lint_checkers   = ['pep8']

" PYMODE.Syntax
let g:pymode_syntax = 1
let g:pymode_syntax_all = 1
let g:pymode_syntax_print_as_function = 1
```

Any help on this would be great. Thanks!

[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Coroutines (`async def` et al) were added in Python 3.5. If your python is less then 3.5 it surely doesn't recognize `async def`.

Test with

```
python --version
```